# Inverse Index comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a very basic inverse index. i.e,

A function `inverseIndex` should take an input of comma separated strings, and then return the set of indexes of the document in which they belong.
 eg: `inverseIndex("Hi Dude","Dude","ok Dude")` ==>`{"Hi":{0}, "Dude":{0,1,2},"ok",{3}}`

As I am from a Java - Javascript background, I wrote it like this in Python without a comprehension:

```
def inverseIndex(strlist):

    strDict = {}
    listOfStrings =  list(enumerate(strlist))

    allKeyWords = set(sum([y.split() for (x,y) in listOfStrings],[]))

    strDict = {};
    for i in allKeyWords :
        setStr = set();
        for j in listOfStrings:
            if(j[1].find(i)):
                setStr.add(j[0])
        strDict[i] = setStr;

    return strDict
```

Here's something I tried:

```
strDict = {}
    listOfStrings =  list(enumerate(strlist))

    # get all the key words segregated in a set so we dont have duplicates.
    allKeyWords = set(sum([y.split() for (x, y) in listOfStrings], []))

    print(allKeyWords)

    return {x: y for x in allKeyWords for (y, z) in listOfStrings if z.find(x) != -1}
```

This looks to be working fine. However, I'm not able to write it using comprehensions.

Also, I'm looking for a way without using `itertools`, if there is any.

Comment: You're not using `itertools`. Also, what have you tried in respect of using comprehensions?

Comment: I've tried this :
   ` strDict = {}
      listOfStrings =  list(enumerate(strlist))
    

    
    #get all the key words segregated in a set so we dont have duplicates.
    allKeyWords = set(sum([y.split() for (x,y) in listOfStrings],[]))

    print(allKeyWords)
    
    return {x:y for x in allKeyWords for (y,z) in listOfStrings if          z.find(x) != -1}`

    
    
    
But what is happening is, the set that is getting created is getting  replaced.Also, I don't want to use itertools yet.

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: As I say, you're not using itertools.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, Is there no other way without importing itertools?

Comment: I'm not telling you to use itertools. Your question says you want to avoid using itertools. I'm telling you that you have already accomplished this.

Comment: Yes, The first method doesn't use itertools, it doesn't use comprehensions either. The second method that I tried uses comprehensions, but it doesn't work. So i want to use comprehension and avoid itertools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

**SCRIPT:**

```
strings = ["Hi Dude", "Dude", "ok Dude"]
dictionary = {}
for i, item in enumerate(strings):
    for word in item.split():
        try:
            dictionary[word].append(i)
        except KeyError:
            dictionary[word] = [i]
```

**DEMO:**

```
print(dictionary)
# {'Dude': [0, 1, 2], 'Hi': [0], 'ok': [2]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this can not be done in a comprehension method, since, you have to check if key is already in the dictionary you are creating at the moment. Consider to use my method instead, which is more pythonic for this problem. Anyway, if you think @abhididdigi that my answer was helpful, don't hesitate, to accept it!